# How to eliminate the need to enclose string property in quotes in html -- Nativescript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a component with property defined: type: string;

When I pass in a type in the html if I add

```
[type]="number"
```

it fails, but if I add the following it works.

```
[type]="'number'"
```

How do I let the property system know that what will be passed in is a string so I don't have to enclose the value in quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails becuase it is looking for a variable in the component called number when you do the following.

`[type]="number"`

---

This works because you are passing a string to [type] by wrapping it

`[type]="'number'"`

Meaning if you really wanted to avoid wrapping it you could define.

```
public number = 'number';
```

or

```
public type = 'number';
[type]="type"
```

But you should probably just stick with wrapping it into a string and stop it from looking for a declared variable if it is static.

---

Optionally you have the ability to pass literal values to an input via omitting the brackets.

```
<my-component type="number"></my-component>
```

"number" is seen as a string literal and used to populate the input value.

Comment: You can also pass literals via omitting the brackets around the attribute altogether IE
`type="number"`

Comment: I always forget that :-), please feel free to edit that into the answer

Comment: It wouldn't work to define it as in your first suggestion because it could be one of several options, i.e. number, telephone, email, social security, etc. but removing the brackets works fine. Thanks for the help!